segfault error 6; Unable to access opcode bytes
I'm trying to learn a bit about binary exploitation and I'm building a minimal sandbox for me to experiment with, but I came across a strange problem. Consider this main.c:
// cat > main.c ; make main
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
        void (*f)(void);
        char * buf = mmap (0, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        struct addrinfo* sa = malloc(sizeof(struct addrinfo));
        sa->ai_family = AF_INET;
        sa->ai_flags = 0;
        sa->ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        sa->ai_protocol = 0;

        int ret = getaddrinfo("localhost", "31337",  NULL, &sa);

        // printf("getaddrinfo: %d\n", ret);

        sa->ai_addr->sa_family = AF_INET;

        ret = connect(fd, sa->ai_addr, sa->ai_addrlen);

        // printf("connect: %d\n", ret);
        // perror("connect");
        read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
        // printf("buf: %s\n", buf);
        f = buf;
        f();
}

And this elo.asm:
; cat > elo.asm ; 
bits 64
xor eax, eax
inc eax
mov bh, 4
int 0x80

I run ncat -k -l --sh-exec "nasm elo.asm  -o /dev/stdout" and then ./main. This works and exits with seemingly random exit codes. The problem manifests when I replace mov bh, 4 with mov ebx, 4. This results in a Segmentation fault, followed by the following dmesg message:
[20096.076031] main[60973]: segfault at 1 ip 00007f6a8ad4f009 sp 00007ffcc6bce518 error 6 likely on CPU 4 (core 4, socket 0)
[20096.076039] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at 0x7f6a8ad4efdf.

What is that and how could I diagnose it? Am I missing some padding?

The code does not test whether mmap succeeded. read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)); is wrong because sizeof(buf) is the size of a pointer, not the size of the buffer. So it could be reading too few bytes. f = buf; does not compile by default with current versions of either Clang or GCC, so it is unclear how you compiled and executed this. Executing dynamic code requires dealing with cache and permission issues, which this code does not do.

Also, verify your pipeline handles zero bytes correctly.

You ought to be isolating potential problems. Test that the nasm command outputs the bytes you expect (by piping them to a command that displays bytes visible, like xxd or od, with appropriate switches). Test that your program reads the bytes you expect. Modify your program to write the bytes into the mapped memory itself, from a hard-coded array of values, so that it does not have any network code in it, and test that it can call the function that way. Get each part working separately before you combine them…

… In any case, isolate the problem to one part of the program that does not work. Do not come to Stack Overflow with an entire program that does not work when it has multiple parts that might be failing. Isolate the problem first.

@EricPostpischil: An ideal command for checking the contents of a flat binary that should have x86 machine code is ndisasm -b64 foo.bin, which will show a hexdump and disassembly.  Wait, this is 64-bit code using int 0x80, not ideal, although should work except in WSL1 or kernels without CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION.  (What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?).  With EBX = 0x????04?? from mov bh, 4, the exit status will be truncated to just the 8-bit of unmodified garbage in BL.  Oh, that's fixed in the answer with EBX

The problem was that I was trying to read sizeof(buf), which is something I accidentally left when changing how buf is constructed. Along with better error checking here's a working version of the code:
/*
This program demonstrates a simple example of a remote code execution
vulnerability. The program connects to a remote server, reads a buffer from
the server and executes it.

To test it, create the following elo.asm file:

    bits 64      ; 64-bit mode
    xor eax, eax ; zero out eax
    inc eax      ; eax = 1
    mov ebx, 4   ; syscall number for sys_exit
    int 0x80     ; call sys_exit

Then set up a server that serves the shellcode, for example:

    ncat -p 31337 -k -l --sh-exec "nasm elo.asm  -o /dev/stdout"

Then run the program and it will execute the shellcode.

WARNING: This program is vulnerable to remote code execution and should not be
used in production. It is only for educational purposes.

*/


#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 4096

int main()
{

        // Let's allocate a buffer with read, write and execute permissions.
        // This way we can write the shellcode to the buffer and execute it.
        // We explicitly set PROT_EXEC to allow the buffer to be executed,
        // bypassing W^X protection.
        char * buf = mmap (0, BUF_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        if (buf == MAP_FAILED) {
                perror("mmap");
                exit(1);
        }

        // Create a socket. This can fail if e.g. the system is out of file
        // descriptors.
        int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (fd == -1) {
                perror("socket");
                exit(1);
        }

        // Allocate a struct addrinfo and set the fields to connect to the
        // server. This can fail if e.g. the system is out of memory.
        struct addrinfo* sa = malloc(sizeof(struct addrinfo));
        if (sa == NULL) {
                perror("malloc");
                exit(1);
        }
        sa->ai_family = AF_INET;
        sa->ai_flags = 0;
        sa->ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        sa->ai_protocol = 0;
        sa->ai_addr->sa_family = AF_INET;

        // Resolve the address of the server. This can fail if e.g. the address
        // is not found.
        int ret = getaddrinfo("localhost", "31337",  NULL, &sa);
        if (ret != 0) {
                perror("getaddrinfo");
                exit(1);
        }

        // Connect to the server. This can fail if e.g. the server is not
        // reachable.
        ret = connect(fd, sa->ai_addr, sa->ai_addrlen);
        if (ret == -1) {
                perror("connect");
                exit(1);
        }

        // Read the shellcode from the server. This can fail if e.g. the server
        // disconnects.
        ret = read(fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
        if (ret == -1) {
                perror("read");
                exit(1);
        }

        // Execute the shellcode. We cast the buffer to a function pointer and
        // call it. If this fails, the shellcode is likely invalid.
        void (*f)(void);
        f = buf;
        f();
}

